# ¿como crear un path que busque solo archivos con cierta extensión en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hola comunidad tengo una duda como puedo crear un `path` que busque solo archivos de tipo json, por ejemplo tengo una carpeta en la cual tengo otros tipos de archivos por ejemplo extensiones `.txt,.xml,.json` y quiero que la ruta solo me busque los archivos con extensión `.json`

este es mi código:

```
    public void PostFile()
            {
                const string DirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\sistemas\Music\PDFprueba\PDFprueba\UploadFile\*json";
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath);

                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    ProcessFileToMongo(fileName);
                }
            }

 public static void ProcessFileToMongo(string fileName)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("ArchivosBD");

            if (fileName.Contains("feedback"))
            {
                return;
            }

            string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);           
            var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(text);
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("XMLs");
            collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero vas a tener que definir la ruta del directorio, luego recorrer todos los archivos y verificar las extensiones de los mismos, si hace matching con el `.json`, procede, dicho en código:

```
//const string DirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\sistemas\Music\PDFprueba\PDFprueba\UploadFile\*json";
const string DirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\sistemas\Music\PDFprueba\PDFprueba\UploadFile";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath);

foreach (string fileName in files)
{
  string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
  if(ext.ToLower() == ".json") {
    ProcessFileToMongo(fileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo, funciono perfectamente!!

Comment: solo una recomendación: evita procesar el mismo archivo 2 veces. Es decir, crea alguna tabla donde almacenes algún ID, nombre de archivo o algo por el estilo y en cada archivo haces una comparación para evitar duplicidad de información :D

Comment: ok entendido tendrás algún link donde pueda buscar información de lo que me comentas

Comment: bro, es solo ir guardando en alguna tabla los nombres de los archivos, luego hacer un método que busque si el nombre de ese archivo existe y que verifique el filename que le estás enviando y de ser falso, procedes a procesarlo. Esta lógica la puedes aplicar con cualquier base de datos y cualquier lenguaje de programación :D te recomiendo sitios como https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/ + https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm + https://Microsoft.com/Learn

Comment: ok ok muchas gracias ya entendí mejor lo que sugerías :)

Comment: perfecto, si tienes dudas, si te has quedado estancado en algún código y has intentado y sigues sin hacerlo funcionar: publica pregunta, estaremos contentos de colaborar :D